#  autorefresh of image saves first image taken

Tags: javascript

i have a camera that saves jpeg pictures which i then upload on my webpage. im using this javsacript code to do autorefresh:

```
function refreshCam()
{   
    document.getElementById("cameraImg").src = "cameraImg.jpeg?a=" + String(new Date().getMilliseconds());
    setTimeout("refreshCam()",500);
}
```

however, the very first image i took pops up in between successive image displays. 
whats worse is that even when i turn off the camera so that no more new images are saved, the picture displayed still continues to change. how do i remove this behavior permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent image "flicker", you can use this technique:

```
function scheduleNextLoad() {
    setTimeout("loadNextImage()", 500);
}

function loadNextImage() {
    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = function() {
        var previousImage = document.getElementById("cameraImg");
        previousImage.parentNode.replaceChild(image, previousImage);
        image.id = previousImage.id;
        scheduleNextLoad();
    }
    image.onabort = scheduleNextLoad;
    image.onerror = scheduleNextLoad;
    image.src = "cameraImg.jpeg?a=" + String(new Date().getMilliseconds());
}
```

What this does is create a new `img` element "on the side", let it load the image in the background and after the image has loaded swap it with the `img` already in the page. The result is that the visual updates happen instantaneously.

Fire off a single `loadNextImage()` to get the ball rolling.

And by the way, the `getMilliseconds()` call is not the best way to go. You might want to  use `getTime()` instead.